# Is it necessary to consider inversion $\left(z\mapsto\dfrac{1}{z}\right)$ on the extended complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis

> Is it necessary to consider **inversion** $\left(z\mapsto\dfrac{1}{z}\right)$ on *extended complex plane* rather than on $\mathbb C$ to map a circle passing through the origin **onto** a st. line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what your source intends "mapping onto" to mean.

One interpretation of "mapping $A$ onto $B$" is that every element of $B$ has an element of $A$ mapped to it--in particular, the mapping needn't be defined on all of $A$, nor must every element of $A$ be mapped to an element of $B$. In this case, you needn't worry about the extended plane.

Another interpretation is that the mapping is defined on all of $A$ and every element of $B$ is has an element of $A$ mapped to it (and possibly also that every element of $A$ is mapped to a point of $B$, so that $A$ is mapped onto *and into* $B$). That would require extending the plane.

Comment: I'm trying to put my question more clearly as: Let $C$ be a circle passing thorugh the origin. Then for $f:C-\{0\}\to\mathbb C:z\mapsto\dfrac{1}{z}$ how would $f(C-\{0\})$ look like? Does ignoring the origin still result a straight line?

Comment: $f(C-\{0\})$ would indeed be a straight line.

Comment: My text says that st. line as a image of the circle. Shouldn't we call the st. line as the image of the circle\{origin}?

Comment: If I'm guessing right as the points come nearer to the origin follwing the boundary of the circle from both sides of the origin the image line keep extending on each sides. Right?

Comment: You are correct about your intuition. Your text, though, is most likely considering things in the extended plane, where a straight line to be a line in your sense, plus the point at infinity, and $z\mapsto\frac1z$ takes $0$ to the point at infinity. If you're familiar with the [Riemann sphere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sphere#Extended_complex_numbers), this is fairly natural. The things we call "straight lines" are just circles in the Riemann sphere passing through the north pole.

Comment: And one more thing. My text break the mapping $T:z\mapsto\dfrac{az+b}{cz+d}(c\ne0)$ into the composition $f_3.f_2.f_1$ of mappings where $f_1:z\mapsto z+\dfrac{d}{c},$$f_2:z\mapsto\dfrac{1}{z},$$f_3:\dfrac{a}{c}-\dfrac{ad-bc}{c^2}z$. Isn't $T(C)$ actually $f_3(f_2[f_1(C)-\{0\}])?$

Comment: Not in general, no. If we were staying in the non-extended plane, we could conclude that $T(C)=f_3(f_2(f_1(C-\{0\})))$ precisely when $d=0$, because otherwise $f_1(0)\ne 0$, and so $T(0)$ is in the non-extended plane. You'd instead want to conclude that $$T(C)=f_3(f_2(f_1(C-\{-d/c\}))).$$

Comment: I'm asking whether $f_3(f_2[f_1(C)-\{0\}])=T(C)$ not whehter $T(C)=f_3(f_2(f_1(C−\{0\})))$

Comment: Ah! I see now. Yes, indeed, you can say that. Again, though, it is more convenient to work in the extended complex plane.

Comment: Thanks so much. I enjoyed your guidance.

Comment: Always glad to help, especially when I'm helping someone with good intuition and curiosity. ^_^

Answer (score 0):

The map does not send a line through origin to circles.

First do not consider extended or not. Any line or circle through origin should be mapped to a line since it is not bounded by inversion map. Any line or circle not containing origin should be mapped to a circle since it is bounded by inversion map.

And considering the extended plane, the infinity point will always be mapped to origin. So any line should be mapped to line or circle containing origin. Any circle should be mapped to line or circle not containing origin.

**Summary**

- Line maps to line/circle through origin
- Circle maps to line/circle not containing origin
- Line/circle through origin maps to line
- Line/circle not containing origin maps to circle

**Edit** I think it does not need to consider the extended complex plane, since in usual a straight line is considered in complex plane, not considering the infinity. But it will depends on the definition what a straight line is.

Comment: Edited...!!!$$$$$$

Comment: @Gobi: I'm not sure if I understand what you're trying to say. Are you trying to tell the poster not to focus so much on the images of individual points?

Comment: @EricStucky I think that the answer depends on what is the definition of a straight line is. So if the definition does not need to contain the infinity point, you don't need to consider the extended complex plane.

Comment: @ Actually, if the definition of a straight line allows it to contain zero, then it will need to the extended complex plane so that $0$ can be mapped to something.